# "SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1103 Incorrect table name error

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to populate the image_tag intermediate table with the ids of the image and the tag, however, I keep getting this error which from what I understand, says the the table name is incorrect even though it is not. It has columns image_id and tag_id which take unsigned integers.

"SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1103 Incorrect table name 'image_tag ' (SQL: insert into `image_tag` (`image_id`, `tag_id`) values (17, 12))"

```
    public function uploadImage(Request $request){
            $this->validate($request, [
                'name' => 'required|max:120',
                'description' => 'max:120|nullable',
                'image' => 'required|max:1999'
            ]);

            $name = $request['name'];
            $description = $request['description'];
            $tag = $request['tags'];
            $userId = auth()->user()->id;
            $file = $request->file('image')->getClientOriginalName();
            $fileName = pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
            $extension = $request->file('image')->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $fileNameToStore = $fileName.'_'.time().'.'.$extension;
            $fileNameToStore = str_replace(' ', '', $fileNameToStore);
            $path = $request->file('image')->storeAs('public/images/uploaded', $fileNameToStore);

            $image = new Image();
            $image->name = $name;
            $image->description = $description;
            $image->user_id = $userId;
            $image->file_name = $fileNameToStore;

            $image->save();
            $image->tags()->attach($tag);

            return redirect()->route('home');
    }
```

Image model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Image extends Model
{
    public function user(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }

    public function tags(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Tag', 'image_tag ','image_id','tag_id');
    }
}
```

Tag model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Tag extends Model
{
    public function images(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Image', 'image_tag','tag_id','image_id');
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you connected to the correct database server/database ?

Comment: Yeah, I can upload new tags and images ( when not trying to connect them to a certain tag ) but now that I'm trying to fill the intermediate table, I get this error.

Comment: could it be eloquent trying to pluralize to `image_tags` ? Do you have anyting in the `image_tag` model ?

Comment: I don't have a image_tag model.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is a space in 'image_tag ' that you wrote :|

```
return $this->belongsToMany('App\Tag', 'image_tag ','image_id','tag_id');
```

Comment: I'm so blind. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Clear your config cache and re-run the migrations.